# How to embbed video on uiview or uiwebview

Tags: iphone

There are some apps in the app store that have a video stream without using mpvideo and they are embbeded on the uiview or uiwebview.
How is this implementation done? Any help is great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably with the standard HTML5 `<video>` tag. It allows you to play a video file that is local or remote. Or even a live stream. Check Apple's [Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/safari) for all details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the HTML code into the webview itself with loadHTMLString:

The method is part of UIWebView and looks something like this:

```
[self.webview loadHTMLString:(NSString *)_some_string baseURL:nil]
```

You can store a basic html page with the embed code for the video in the _some_string variable and it will load up that page with the embed code.

```
NSString *html = @"\
<html>\
    <head></head>\
    <embed code for video here>\
</body></html>";

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complicated solution due to the way Apple has videos setup.

Create an HTML file with a basic HTML5 video player, with source="video/you/want". Be sure to add **webkit-playsinline** to the video.

```
<video  width=“320” height=“240” webkit-playsinline><source src=“sample_iPod.m4v”/></video>
```

Add this player.html as a resource to your Xcode project.

Create a UIWebView, hook it up in the Storyboard editor, and then do the following in ViewDidLoad:

```
//set the webView delegate - hook up in Storyboard as well!

self.webView.delegate = self;

//initialize our HTML path - the file is player.html in our project

NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”player” ofType:@”html”];

//encode the path

NSString *escapedPath = [htmlPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//webview needs NSURL, so let’s make one

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedPath];

//load the request in the webview

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Finally, the key step, be sure to flag the view to allow inline playback.

```
//flag the webview to play inline

self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

I wrote a post with more details [here](http://nicroth.tumblr.com/post/28600266623/how-to-add-inline-auto-playing-video-to-an-ios-app).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-mp4\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}